# Closest Vector Problem in the 1-Norm. Mixed-Integer Linear Programming Formulation

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, integer-lattices, mixed-integer-programming

So I understand the closest vector problem in the infinity-norm and getting to the final step of the program where I have:

Minimize z 
Subject to z >= xj - tj for j = 1,2,...,n
           z >= tj - xj for j = 1,2,...,n

Okay so how do I do the exact same thing except in the 1-Norm?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MathJax, please.

Comment: Minimize sum(zj) Subject to zj >= xj - tj for j = 1,2,...,n zj >= tj - xj for j = 1,2,...,n